# NDSolve::ndcf: Repeated convergence test failure; unable to continue

Tags: differential-equations, stiffness

I have been trying to solve this system of differential equations:

```
eq1 = D[ϕ[X], {X, 2}] - 2./3*D[ϕ[X], X]^2 + 1. - 
   8.*Pi*Exp[2.*ϕ[X]]*(D[ν[X], {X, 2}]/(12.*Pi) + (D[ν[X], X])^2/(24.*Pi));
eq2 = -D[ν[X], X]*D[ϕ[X], X] + 4./3*D[ϕ[X], X]^2 - 1. - 
   8.*Pi*Exp[2.*ϕ[X]]*(-D[ν[X], X]^2/(24.*Pi));

sol = NDSolve[{
   eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0,
   ϕ[1.] == -0.6506712457245407, ν[1.] == -0.7061222993948587,
   ϕ'[1.] == -1.1423912339336473}, 
   {ϕ, ν}, {X, 0.01, 1}, 
   MaxSteps -> Infinity, 
   Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}, 
   Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"
]
```

and I can't figure out how to fix the error

> NDSolve::ndcf: Repeated convergence test failure at X == 0.707883; unable to continue.

I would greatly appreciate if you could help me resolve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's help `NDSolve` a bit by differentiating `eq2` and writing down the initial condition for `D[ν[X], X]` explicitly:

```
eq1 = D[ϕ[X], {X, 2}] - 1/3  2.  D[ϕ[X], X]^2 + 1. - 
      8. π Exp[2. ϕ[X]] (D[ν[X], {X, 2}]/(12. π) + D[ν[X], X]^2/(24. π));

eq2 = -D[ν[X], X] D[ϕ[X], X] + 1/3 4. D[ϕ[X], X]^2 - 1. - 
     (8. π Exp[2. ϕ[X]] (-D[ν[X], X]^2))/(24. π);

ic = {ϕ[1.] == -0.6506712457245407, 
      ν[1.] == -0.7061222993948587, ϕ'[1.] == -1.1423912339336473};

newic = Equal @@@ Flatten[Solve[eq2 == 0, D[ν[X], X]]] /. X -> 1. /. Rule @@@ ic
(* {ν'[1.] == -11.9071, ν'[1.] == -0.685106} *)

sollst = (NDSolveValue[{eq1 == 0, D[eq2, X] == 0, 
                        ic, #1}, {ϕ, ν}, {X, 0.01, 1}] &) /@ newic

sollst // Map@ListLinePlot
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) It is not clear why `NDSolve` can't solve this system directly as it is. Without any options `NDSolve` computes one branch of solution only up to `X == 0.434532`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I think it's because the pre-processor of `NDSolve` isn't clever enough to transform the system to a standard ODE system (the pre-processor of `NDSolve` never tries to differentiate the equation), and `NDSolve`'s DAE solver is generally weaker than its ODE solver.

Comment: @AlexTrounev It is straightforward to eliminate `ν[X]`, converting this DAE system to a single ODE, but even then I encounter the error you did at X == 0.434532 for the second soluton under some circumstances, for instance by increasing `WorkingPrecision`.  Part of the problem is that `1/(-9 + 16 E^(2 ϕ[X])` occurs in the transformed ODE, and that quantity becomes large at `x = 0.668118`.  But, I believe that something else also causes the second solution to be very sensitive.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Sorry, but I didn't do anything. :) I took options from `NDSolve` and it computed solution up to `X == 0.434532`, while with options it stops at `X == 0.707883`. It is not clear why `NDSolve` can't compute second branch of solution automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved my problem.